# Extract poster image from video

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, html5-video

I want to extract my poster image from the video file itself and wish to use that one on the web page.

My technology stack consists of spring mvc, hibernate, jpa, jQuery, jsp, html5, css3.

Can anyone guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @sjm, I played around with Popcorn.capture and tried the following code which does the trick

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Popcorn.capture.js Functional Examples</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.popcornjs.org/code/dist/popcorn.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/popcorn.capture.js"></script>
</head>
<body  onload="myFunction()">

  <div id="unmoved-fixture">
        <video height="180" width="300" id="video-target" controls>
        <source src="assets/popcorntest.mp4"></source>
        <source src="assets/popcorntest.ogv"></source>
        <source src="assets/popcorntest.webm"></source>
        </video>
  </div>
<pre>



</pre>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var $pop = Popcorn( "#video-target" ),
    poster;

    $pop.capture({
    at: 10
    });
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code captures the image from 10th second of video and creates poster image for video.

You can get popcorn.capture.js from https://github.com/rwaldron/popcorn.capture/tree/master/src

Answer (score 8):

Depends where your wanting to do the processing, heres a couple of options

**Pre-processing Option**
If your preprocessing your video, you can use Grunt to generate different video formats/sizes/images with https://github.com/sjwilliams/grunt-responsive-videos

**Client-side Option**
If your wanting to generate it client-side, you can use something like Popcorn.capture as long as your hosting your own Video file, otherwise you will run into the Same Origin Policy issue. See https://github.com/rwaldron/popcorn.capture

**Server-side Option**
If you wanting to generate it Server-side, Humble-Video https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video is a Java framework to work with video files

Comment: I am trying to work with Popcorn.capture with some sample videos. But struggling to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible using html5 and canvas

Github [here](https://github.com/codepo8/videograbber)

See it in action [here](http://isithackday.com/videograbber/)

More details here - [CREATING SCREENGRABS FROM HTML5 VIDEO WITH CANVAS](http://christianheilmann.com/2011/07/01/creating-screengrabs-from-html5-video-with-canvas/)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Taking screengrabs from video in Canvas</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<style>
  *{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:15px;font-family:calibri,arial,sans-serif}
  footer,section,header{display:block;}
  body{padding:2em;background:#666;color:#fff;}
  h1{font-size:24px;margin:10px 0;}
  h2{font-size:18px;margin:10px 0;color:lime;}
  canvas{display:block;border:2px solid #000;}
  #video,#canvas{float:left;padding-right:10px;}
  #video{width:640px;}
  #save li{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}
  #save{clear:both;padding:10px 0;overflow:auto;}
  #save img{float:left;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:5px;}
  footer a{color:lime;}
  footer p{margin:5em 0 1em 0;padding:1em 0;border-top:1px solid #999}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <header><h1>Taking screengrabs from video in Canvas (Chrome, Mozilla, Opera, Safari - maybe IE (got no windows))</h1></header>
  <section>
    <p>Simply play the video. Every time you pause, you can see the screenshot on the right. Click the screenshot to store it in your collection below.</p>
<div id="video">
  <h2>The Video:</h2>
  <video controls>
    <source src="meetthecubs.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    <source src="meetthecubs.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
  </video>
</div>
<div id="canvas">
  <h2>Preview (click to store images below):</h2>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
<div id="save">
  <h2>Your saved images:</h2>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
</section>
<footer>
  <p>Written by 
    <a href="http://wait-till-i.com/">Chris Heilmann</a> - 
    <a href="http://twitter.com/codepo8">@codepo8</a>
  </p>
</footer>
<script>

(function(){

  var v = document.querySelector('video'),
      n = document.querySelector('source').src.replace(/.*\/|\..*$/g,''),
      c = document.querySelector('canvas'),
      save = document.querySelector('#save ul'),
      ctx = c.getContext('2d');

  v.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function(ev){

    var ratio = v.videoWidth/v.videoHeight,
        w = 400,
        h = parseInt(w / ratio, 10),
        time = 0,
        img = null,
        li = null;

    c.width = w;
    c.height = h + 40;

    v.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(ev){
      if(v.paused){
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.drawImage(v, 0, 40, w, h);
        ctx.font = '20px Calibri';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
        ctx.fillText(n, 5, 20);
        time = format(v.currentTime);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillText(time, 395 - ctx.measureText(time).width, 20);
      }
    },false);

    c.addEventListener('click',function(ev){
      li = document.createElement('li');
      img = document.createElement('img');
      li.appendChild(img);
      save.appendChild(li);
      img.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    },false);

  },false);

  function format(time){
    var hours = parseInt((time / 60 / 60) % 60, 10),
        mins = parseInt((time / 60) % 60, 10),
        secs = parseInt(time, 10) % 60,
        hourss = (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + parseInt(hours, 10) + ':',
        minss = (mins < 10 ? '0' : '') + parseInt(mins, 10) + ':',
        secss  = (secs < 10 ? '0' : '') +(secs % 60),
        timestring = ( hourss !== '00:' ? hourss : '' ) + minss + secss;
    return timestring;
  };
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure you have the video source correct.

Comment: How do I remove a SecurityError where the the context generates image from the video . I tried adding this to code `v.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous');`